# Why did Ivan and Darusya travel part of the way to town by horse-drawn carts?

Tags: historical-context, ukrainian-language, maria-matios, sweet-darusya

*Sweet Darusya* periodically refers to horse-drawn carts being in contemporary use. For example, in one particular scene in the book, cars, bicycles, and horse-drawn carts were all in use at the same time. At a different part in the novel, Ivan takes Darusya to town (partially to see the regional doctor for her headaches and apparent muteness). They travel part of the way by horse-drawn cart and part of the way by bus. Why did they do that? Was that actually common in rural Ukraine at the time?